# NetFramework 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 what version includes?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, .net-framework

I have downloaded the installer of

Net Framework 4  `dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64`  48mb;

Net Framework 4.5.1 `NDP451-KB2872776-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe` 136mb;

Net Framework 4.5.2 `NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe` 66.7mb;

And wondering what version includes each of these package (so if 4.5.1 includes 4, I could avoid to install both ...and so on)

Answer (score 0):

.Net 4.5.2 replaces .net 4.0 and 4.5.1. Install `NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe` and you use the latest version.

Comment: thanks for the answer. this means that 4.5.2 includes all previous? I have read tha is important have all runtimes for net framework and visual c++ redist since some programs may need a specific version.

Comment: yes, 4.5.2 includes all former .Net 4.x versions, but NOT 3.5.